# Munchausen's: Can someone believe falsely that they do/don't have it?

Tags: logic

I am working construction for the summer before I go to college and I have too many hours to think while labouring.

For some odd reason, [Munchausen's disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munchausen_syndrome) crossed my mind and I couldn't get this strange logical scenario out of my head (for the purposes of this question, think of Munchausen's as a disorder that causes one to believe that they are ill, going to die, or simply diseased with no medical backing).

I got thinking, can someone actually have a false belief about whether or not they have this disorder? I reached the conclusion that someone can't have such a false belief for logical reasons. See my answer below, PLEASE add your own though. :)

Comment: if munchausen's disease is a disease then i guess you can't believe you have it and not have it. if it isn't then ofc, i'm not sure why you wouldn't get that. seems like one of those v trivial pseudo paradoxes.

Comment: Everyone with it falsely claims they don't have it.  If they admitted they had it, the delusion of physical causes for their symptoms would go away, and they would no longer have it (a least with regard to those symptoms).  It is possible to worry that you have a delusion, but it is not possible to worry that you don't have a delusion.

Answer (score 1):

**OP PROPOSITION**

I reached the conclusion that someone basically can't have a false belief about their status of this disorder. Consider the following cases:

**Case 1: Suppose Person A has Munchausen's, and Person A believes that they do**

We have no conflict between our presupposition and belief here, so Person A is correct!

**Case 2: Suppose Person B does not have Munchausen's, and they do not believe that they do**

Again, no conflict between our presupposition and belief, so Person B is also correct!

**Case 3: Suppose Person C has Munchausen's, but they do not believe this to be true**

Ah, finally, a conflict. Here's where things get interesting. If Person C does not believe that they have Munchausen's, they are clearly denying that they have a disorder. Supposing they did have the disorder--which causes those affected to believe they have diseases they don't--then they shouldn't be denying the diagnosis, they should be embracing it! In fact, the very denial of a positive diagnosis is strong evidence against the disorder, leading me to believe that maybe they don't actually have Munchausen's at all!

**Case 4: Suppose Person D does not Have Munchausen's, but they believe that they do**

Aha, similar to the last situation. We suppose that this individual lacks the disorder, but their very denial of this presupposition is insistence that they have a disorder they supposedly do not, which leads us to believe that our presupposition is false and they do in fact have the disease

So there we have it. In each case, the person's belief about whether they have Munchausen's proves to be correct, sometimes in contradiction with the initial diagnosis/presupposition.

Alright, so I know this is obviously very generalized, for someone could actually have Munchausen's and deny that they do because they know it's not "really" a disease, but aside from these kinds of objections I found this entire situation extremely bizarre yet super interesting to contemplate.

I'd like to hear thoughts (good or bad) on this scenario and know if anyone has seen anything similar to this in philosophy class, readings, or whatever. I've taken a philosophy of theology course but as for this kind of philosophy I plead ignorance. Thanks.

Comment: neat presentation, but i'm *sure* you're wrong. not ftr or anything, but i've long wondered why i was being treated for psychosis. if this was a genuine logical paradox, then someone would've twigged, tbh

Answer (score 1):

There is a disparity between your reasoning and conclusion signaled by the contrast between "shouldn't", "is strong evidence against", "leads us to believe", "maybe", etc., vs. "can't". Having a disorder that inclines you to believe that you have diseases you don't does not mean that you will believe it of every disease every time (case 3). Even more so, not having the disorder does not mean that you can not exhibit a symptom of it (case 4), that would be a case of [affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent). You *can* make an exception for Munchausen's in cases 3 and 4.

This is similar to the situation with the [paradox of Epimenides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimenides_paradox#Logical_paradox), the original Liar paradox, "Epimenides the Cretan says that all Cretans are liars". It only works as a paradox if "liar" means "lies about everything all the time", which is not what it conventinally means. There is a similar issue in the classical [anti-sceptical argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-refuting_idea#Philosophical_skepticism): sceptic's assertion that "there are no truths" creates a problem for the sceptic, who appears to utter one, only if "no truths" is artificially universalized to include the assertion itself. In fact, both examples suggest that in colloquial use the context does limit the scope in such cases.

But you can equalize the strength of your verbs by altering the conventional meaning of "Munchausen's" to "believes he has every disease he meets", as logicians did with the "liar". Then we arrive at one of the so-called [self-defeating ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-refuting_idea), "*whose falsehood is a logical consequence of the act or situation of holding them to be true*". In your cases the "self-defeat" is not quite the "logical consequence" of the context, but is only "strongly suggested" by it. This likens them to the so-called [Moore sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-refuting_idea), like "It is raining but I do not believe that it is"/"It is not raining but I believe that it is", which are not strictly speaking inconsistent. Compare to "It is raining but *he* does not believe that it is", which is not even paradoxical.

Comment: I can tell you read very well into my post, for these are the very objections I had (evidence =/= proof). Not only that, but I actually had the liar's paradox in the back of my mind when I made this post, for I came across it while reading up on Godel's incompleteness theorem. Upvote given, I'll probably select as well if a better answer isn't posted.